# Where is a website that lists non-traditional genre RPG scenarios and systems

Tags: system-agnostic

I mean not science fiction, not fantasy, not horror.

My Japanese wife (passable English) said she is interested to try doing RPG but she has no interest in those genres- she has seen a few movies. She like reading School Manga so that's a possible area. I found one- Nicotine Girls but she wouldn't interested in that. Where would I find a list- preferable with current links?

Comment: Google is probably helpful for this, actually. Failing that, asking on an [RPG discussion forum](http://forum.rpg.net) is likely to get an avalanche of suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Non-genre is pretty tough to find given the general RPG industry, but here's a couple of publishers, with at least a few games I know of:

1. [Black & Green games](http://www.blackgreengames.com/games.html) (recommended: Breaking the Ice, Shooting the Moon).
2. [TAO Games](http://www.tao-games.com/) (recommended: Clover, Drifter's Escape.  Hot Guys Making Out might also work depending on how she feels about historical genre).
3. [Indie Press Revolution](http://www.indiepressrevolution.com/xcart/home.php) has a ton of games, but I really recommend [Primetime Adventures](http://www.indiepressrevolution.com/xcart/product.php?productid=16594&cat=0&bestseller=Y).

And a game recommendation - [The Friendship Game](http://guyshalev.wordpress.com/2010/06/16/the-friendship-game-v2-an-old-new-game/) (free PDF) - designed to do light hearted stories of drama - you can add or remove genre bits as you see fit.

Answer (score 10):

[RPG Geek](http://rpggeek.com/browse/rpg) contains a phenomenally huge list of RPGs - over 4,600 at the time of writing. Among them are quite a few RPGs that can support non-sci fi, non-fantasy, non-horror games. In fact, Fiasco, the second on the list at the moment, is none of those.

At the top of the page is an [advanced search](http://rpggeek.com/advsearch/rpg) that you can use to search by genre, and thus simply eliminate the genres you're not interested in.

Comment: I checked that it has very few and none relevant to me. Its so traditional genre focused.

Comment: @user2617804 Yes, "traditional" is the majority. RPGGeek isn't just traditional games, but since it aims to catalogue all RPGs, of course you will see more traditional genres there. Keep digging. May I suggest using the "Social" genre filter with the "Core Rules" item filter? [The results are much less traditional.](http://rpggeek.com/geeksearch.php?objecttype=rpgitem&advsearch=1&action=search&q=&include[rpgdesignerid]=&geekitemname=&include[rpgpublisherid]=&geekitemname=&range[yearpublished][min]=&range[yearpublished][max]=&searchuser=eggdropsoap&propertyids[]=2083&familyids[]=612&B1=Search)

Comment: If you're not finding it there, odds are it's one of (1) brand new, (2) in Japanese (3) in korean, or (4) not written. And even a large chunk of the Japanese games are listed. It's rare to find a game in a European language that's not in the database.

Comment: @user2617804 If non-traditional is not the _only_ condition on what you're after, consider asking a game-recommendation question describing the qualities you _are_ after in a game.